# indices examined during binary search

Tags: c++, binary-search

I'm going through my C++ book and I have a question about binary search. There is an array called `critter` which is filled with (in order) = `{auk, bat, cow, eel, elk, fox, gnu, pig, rat}`

So if I wanted to find eel, I believe would go through the indices 4 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 from the formula given in my book. But what if you want to search for something not in the array?

The book tells me the algorithm is

```
set found = false
set first = 0
set last = n - 1 (n being the number of elements)
while first <= last and !found do following:
    a) Calc loc = (first+last)/2
    b) if item < a[loc] then
           set last = loc - 1
       else if a[loc] > item  then
           set first = loc + 1
       else
           set found = true
    end while
```

so if the item is not there, would it just jump down to found = true, since it can't be < or >? Or would it go though every index in the array?

Comment: [`std::binary_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/), [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/)

Comment: 4-1-2-3 is not what I think. 4-2-3 sounds better. And what´s the real question? If the searched element isn´t there, it isn´t there.

Comment: the question is the give the indices of the elements in the order that the components are examined during a binary search. So it first looks at 4. eel is < array[4] so last becomes 4 - 1 = 3. the next thing searched is (first(0) + last(3))/2 which rounds to 1 since its an int. its > than [1] so first becomes 0 + 1 =1. then ( 1 + 3)/2 = 2, its > 2 so first again increased to be 1 + 1 =2. Then it looks at (2+3)/2 = 2 and [2] < the item. So again increase first now we have (3+3)/2 = 3 and its at [3] so its found. At least that's how I follow it.

Answer (score 0):

You will notice that the loop will exit when `first` is not smaller than `last`: `while first <= last`.

When that happens before found is set to true then you return false.